# Concept for communcation of a RaspberryPi 2 on the Internet of Things

Tags: raspberry-pi, communication, raspberry-pi2, iot

I'm currently writing a thesis about the Internet of Things. It includes connecting a RaspberryPi 2 to the Internet and evaluating the possibilities of communication, that means type of connection (i guess LAN or WLAN) and how to set up the connection. Also I have to measure different criteria, like the amount of data that is transferred, the speed and so on. 
I have never worked with a RasPi before, so does anybody have a suggestion on how I can measure these parameters like amount of data and speed properly?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the wrong questions. I RPi has a 100M ethernet port, this does not mean it will transmit 100mbit/s worth data. This totally depends on the application.

Suppose the Pi is thing which transmits temperature once a second. Let´s suppose temperature value occupies 4 bytes and minimum TCP header is 20 bytes, so each  second the Pi will transmit something around 24 bytes (excluding negotiation connection, acks, errors, etc). This is a oversimplification of the problem to illustrate that RPi has nothing to do with the amount of data transmitted by IOT.

Now, imagine the opposite. RaspberryPi is not a thing anymore, but a central node receiving temperatures report from a bunch of nodes around a building. How much data RPi would be receiving? Depends on how many sensors are out there. RPi will also only transmits a few bytes of `ack` in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So you suggest that i should just focus on one certain application to measure these parameters?

Comment: @wiesel, yes. I would focus on application, let´s say a building control for instance. It would have a bunch of sensors and actuators (humidity/temp sensor, light switches, thermostats, door open/close sensors. You can measure the amount of data produced by each one of these "things" and compose a study over how much data a small, medium or large build would consume.

Comment: In other words, RPi by itself is just a computer.